# Rbind arrays by names

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have two named arrays, possibly with different lengths

```
row1<-c(a="a1",b="b1",c="c1")
row2<-c(a="a1",d="d1",b="b2",c="c2")
```

I would like to bind them maintaining the order of the names, that is the outcome should be:

```
      a    d    b    c   
row1 "a1"  NA  "b1" "c1"
row2 "a1" "d1" "b2" "c2"
```

but using the usual *rbind* the outcome is instead

```
       a    d    b    c   
row1 "a1" "b1" "c1" "a1"
row2 "a1" "d1" "b2" "c2"
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest

```
n = sort(union(names(row1),names(row2)))
rbind(row1[n], row2[n])

#      a    b    c    <NA>
# [1,] "a1" "b1" "c1" NA  
# [2,] "a1" "b2" "c2" "d1"
```

If many rows are involved, you can do

```
myrows = list(row1,row2)
n = sort(Reduce(union, lapply(myrows, "names")))
do.call(rbind, lapply(myrows, `[`, n))
```

.

---

The question is tagged with data.frame, but the example uses matrices. With data.frames, I would use one of these packages:

```
# new example
r1<-data.frame(a="a1",b="b1",c="c1", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
r2<-data.frame(a="a1",d="d1",b="b2",c="c2", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(r1,r2), fill=TRUE)

#     a  b  c  d
# 1: a1 b1 c1 NA
# 2: a1 b2 c2 d1

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(r1, r2)

#       a     b     c     d
#   (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
# 1    a1    b1    c1    NA
# 2    a1    b2    c2    d1
```

Similarly, if many rows are involved, `rs = list(r1,r2)`, you can do `rbindlist(rs, fill=TRUE)` or `do.call(bind_rows, rs)`.